# Finding use of == or != for a specific class in huge Java code

Tags: java, comparison, equals

I need to replace every use of == and != for one class by the proper call to equals method, but this class is very often used and spending hours to track every single reference of the class to check if it is compared somewhere in each peace of code seems a daunting task.

Is there a way to find all use of == and != with this specific class as it would be possible to find all calls to a method of this class ?

I'm currently using eclipse but if some other tool does the job I'll use it !

I found nothing about such a problem. Am I missing something here that makes it irrelevant ?
(please spare us the "you should have used equals in the first place", it's not my code nor my did. I'm looking for solutions)

Comment: You could use PMD, and list all the violations of the rule [CompareObjectsWithEquals](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-4.3.0/rules/design.html#CompareObjectsWithEquals). That would allow you to fix all the places where objects, whatever their type is, are not compared with equals. Why are you concerned about a single class? You should never compare objects with ==, unless they are enums.

Comment: You should have used equals!! jk. This may indeed be a problem you have here. I haven't heard of anything like that in eclipse. One way of doing it would be to search all occurences of `object ==` and `object !=` and replace them with `object.equals(` and `!object.equals(`. After this just fix all the errors eclipse reports because of codepieces such as `object.equals(o2`

Comment: @JBNizet == and != are useful when comparing references.

Comment: @OlaviMustanoja but comparing references is almost always a bug. Object's equals() implementation compares references anyway.

Comment: @JBNizet that is most of the time untrue. almost all of my overrides of equals() simply compares the hashcodes, which are usually generated by something trivial such as posX and posY, and I don't think I'm retarded for doing so. comparing references is almost always a bug? sure... unless it was meant to compare references... duh

Comment: @OlaviMustanoja then all your overrides are buggy. Assuming posX and posY are integers, there are 2^64 possible combinations of posX and posY. But there are only 2^32 posible values of hashCode. You thus have a big probability of having two objects with different posX and posY, but with the same hashCode. Could you give me a reasonable use-case where you don't want two equal objects to be considered equal if they're not the same object?

Comment: @JBNizet again with the context. In the example I gave it was a search algorithm in a rather small grid (100x100), which gives me 100 possible values for posX and 100 possible values for posY. I stand by my statement. I think it is general practice to override equals to compare the contents of objects.

Comment: Why do you think such a PMD rule exists? It's not even in the *controversial* ruleset. Also, you started by saying that *almost all of my overrides of equals() simply compares the hashcodes*. And then you justified your buggy implementation by saying that *the example I gave it was a search algorithm in a rather small grid (100x100)*. Should I deduce that *almost all your overrides* consists in a single one?

Comment: @JBNizet I can give you a reasonable use case. Say I was implementing an A* search algorithm between two points in the said 100x100 grid, and after finding the shortest path, I wanted to get the actual path between the points. I would implement a class Path, which illustrates a taken path in the grid. An object of Path would hold the posX and posY in the grid where it currently ends, as well as an ArrayList of Points that include the past locations and a score that would be calculated with appropriate heuristics. Now I want to store the path objects in a PriorityQueue that sorts by score...

Comment: @JBNizet when adding new path to the list of visited paths, I want to see if the list contains another path that has the same posX and posY, and add the new path to the queue only if the current path has a lower score than the existing. I have no reason not to override the equals method of Path to only compare the posX and posY

Comment: And, where is the use of == that can't be replaced by the use of equals() in this example? Hint: `list.contains()` uses `equals()`.

Comment: That's not the point. The point is that many implementations of equals, good or bad, do not check for reference, and thus it is good practice to use equals with the assumption that it only compares content, and use == where it is necessary to compare references. I for one am not going to read through the myriads of lines in java's and others' source code to see whether or not their equals() compare references.

Comment: Of course an override of `equals()` should not check for reference equality. Otherwise, it would be useless, since Object.equals() does that by default. The point is: it's almost always a bug to compare references. In 99.99% of the cases, when you compare objects, you want to test if they're functionally equal. Not if they are the exact same object. That's why I asked you to give me a reasonable use case where you would want to compare by reference instead of comparing using equals().

Comment: I think you are both right : indeed there is a use for both equals and !=/== which have different meaning, but as the code I'm working on has mistaken use of !=/== it's probably a good idea that I check all of them using the PMD solution :) Whenever I find the time for it ! In the meantime I'll give a try to the Olavi's solution !  
 
 I'll have a hard time choosing the "better" answer, but if you were to post your useful comments as answer I would work on it :D 

Thanks again :)

Comment: @JB Nizet Maybe on a server working on data sent to it from several different computers, it might happen that it receive data objects to compute that are "equals" but loaded from different deserialization and thus "different" to the server which might have to compare references to distinguish the two objects ? IDK if it would make sens.